# Variables in modules in PowerShell

Tags: powershell, module

I have a main script, where a few constants are defined. I then have a module (psm1) to include helper functions. The details are:

In the main script, I have imported the module as an object:

```
$cud2ADhleper = Import-Module -Force $cud2ADhelperModule -AsCustomObject
```

In the module, I have two variables,

```
[string]$SQLServer = $null

Function SetSQLServerAddr ([string] $name)
{
    $SQLServer = $name
}
Function GetSQLServerAddr
{
    return $SQLServer
}
```

My understanding is that because I am not exporting `$SQLServer` from the module, this variable should be local, and I should be able to Set/Get it.

It turns out otherwise. After I called `SetSQLServerAddr ([string] $name)`, then callling `GetSQLServerAddr` returns $null. What did I miss?

Answer (score 46, accepted):

```
Function SetSQLServerAddr ([string] $name)
{
    $SQLServer = $name
}
```

That creates a new *local* `$SQLServer` in the scope of that function.

If you want to update a variable at module (`.psm1`) scope then you need to prefix the name to indicate that:

```
Function SetSQLServerAddr ([string] $name)
{
    $script:SQLServer = $name
}
```

For more on scopes see [`get-help about_scopes`](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh847849.aspx).

Comment: I have been looking all over and have read about_scopes but it was still not clear to me that a variable defined in a module can be set using the script scope in a function within the module. Script scope sounds like it is is a misnomer in the context of a module and should be called module scope or something like that. Thank you for your answer!

Comment: @ChrisMagnuson I agree the name isn't great, but it does make sense (the relevant difference from a "normal" script is that module state persists after returning to the caller).